# How do I update a tqdm progress bar with line size?

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm trying to load a file in Python2.7 (Ubuntu 16.04), and display the current progress with [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    vectors = {}
    tq = tqdm(f, total=os.path.getsize(filename))
    for line in tq:
        vals = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        vectors[vals[0]] = np.array([float(x) for x in vals[1:]])
        tq.update(len(line))
```

It's not working though, the ETA is way too big.  It kind of [follows this example](http://blog.nelsonliu.me/2016/07/30/progress-bars-for-python-file-reading-with-tqdm/), but I was trying to do as said in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the key was not passing the file object as the 'iterable' argument for tqdm and manually managing the updates instead:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

filename = '/home/nate/something.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # unit='B' and unit_scale just prettifies the bar a bit
    tq = tqdm(total=os.path.getsize(filename), unit='B', unit_scale=True)
    for line in f:
        tq.update(len(line))
```

Comment: note that this will only work correctly for binary files.